# Opening multiple files at once using Explorer in Ubuntu/WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run `explorer.exe filename.pdf` in Ubuntu under WSL, the PDF opens.

However, when I run `explorer.exe *.pdf`, either in a for loop or on its own, it just opens File Explorer with no PDF.  Why is this and how can I open multiple PDFs at one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the way that Windows Explorer works -- To my knowledge, it never accepts multiple file names, even under CMD or PowerShell.  Running `explorer *.pdf` from PowerShell has the same result as in Ubuntu.

You mention a `for` loop, but you don't provide any code in your question.  That *is* the proper way to do this.  The following works fine for me:

```
for pdf in *.pdf; do explorer.exe "$pdf"; done
```

Alternatively, to select just certain files:

```
for pdf in a.pdf b.pdf; do explorer.exe "$pdf"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, introducing sleep works for me.. For applications that take sometime to load, I set sleep for more seconds.. e.g.,

```
while IFS= read -r table_prefix; do
               # Open the file
               explorer.exe "${table_prefix}"* > /dev/null 2>&1 &
               sleep 10
           done < "$text_file"
```

This opens separate word table documents